# can't add mysql and mysqli php extensions on Debian

Tags: php, docker, debian

I am building a Docker container using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client
```

On php.ini, I enabled both mysql and mysqli extensions:

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

When running the container, I get the following php errors:

```
PHP startup: unable to load dynamic library '..pdo_mysql.so'.
PHP startup: unable to load dynamic library '..php_mysqli.so'.
```

Shouldn't the installation of mysql-client package have added these extensions?
What can be the problem?

Comment: No it wont your installing the cli client, not the server nor the php module, you will need `php5-mysql`

Comment: You also wont need to fiddle with php.ini them lines will be automatically set as the config loader will go through the conf.d/mods-enabled folder.

Comment: and dont forget you got `docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql`

Comment: Don't you also need to install the actual server `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks!! the docker-php-ext-install did the trick. For some reason apt-get install php5-mysql is aborted and I get "E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate". Only after I commented-out this line, then the docker-php-ext-install script ran and created the extensions, though it showed some red warning lines about missing extension files. Any idea why the package is not found?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone If you post it as an answer I will approve. Thanks again for helping